# How to disable app notifications of a certain app?

Tags: applications, notifications, notification-icons, push-notifications

How can I disable the app notifications of a certain app I installed from Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a notification off an app by following the steps below:

> **Note:** This guide is made on **Android Lollipop** and it can vary per **device**/**Android version**.

1. Open Settings:

[image]

2. Scroll down till you see **Apps** and click it:

[image]

3. Search for the app that you want to disable the notifications of:

[image]

4. Now uncheck **Show notifications** and tap OK:

[image]

5. Now your notifications of the app should be disabled.

Hope my answer helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

The other way around is

**Lollipop** 
*Settings -> Sound & Notification -> App Notifications -> Select a app and block*

**Old Versions**

*Settings -> Apps / Application Manager -> Select app -> Un-tick Show Notifications*