# Permanently disable app notifications (lollipop 5.0.2)

Tags: applications, root-access, notifications

I am running `lollipop 5.0.2` on a `Motorola Moto G 2014`.

I would like to permanently disable notifications for specific apps. However, when I untick `Show notifications` in the settings for some apps, this is sometimes being reinstated automatically.

I am unsure as to whether this is happening when updating the apps, or whether the apps themselves are running a check to see that their notifications are enabled.

Is there a stronger solution to block app notifications?

This can include processes that require `root` access to the device.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with this approach: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112564/114557

Explicitly `Block` an application under the `Sound & notification->App notifications` settings.

Comment: No app should be able to re-enable the 'show notifications' checkbox unless it has root access. Is there any pattern amongst apps for which notifications re-enable themselves?

Comment: I noticed it initially with SUPERCELL's game, Boom Beach.

Comment: Running 5.0.2 and this thing still shows me that app/s were updated even though i unchecked the notifications checkbox under PlayStore settings.

Comment: Go to settings>sound and notifications>app notifications. Turn them off from there.